# How do I show a link to the user registration page only to anonymous users?

Tags: routes, 8

I want to show anonymous users a "Register" link.

So, in `mymodule.menu.yml`:

```
mymodule.userregister:
  title: 'Register an Account'
  url: 'internal:/user/register'
  weight: 10
  menu_name: account
```

This adds a register link to the account menu next to the login/logout link-- great!  Except it also shows up for authenticated users, who get an "access denied" error if they click it.

I looked in `user.links.menu.yml` in `code/modules/user` to try to find something I could use:

```
user.page:
  title: 'My account'
  weight: -10
  route_name: user.page
  menu_name: account
user.logout:
  weight: 10
  menu_name: account
  class: Drupal\user\Plugin\Menu\LoginLogoutMenuLink
```

I also checked `user.routing.yml`:

```
user.register:
  path: '/user/register'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'user.register'
    _title: 'Create new account'
  requirements:
    _access_user_register: 'TRUE'

user.logout:
  path: '/user/logout'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\user\Controller\UserController::logout'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

I'm stumped.  **How can I make my menu link only show up for anonymous users?**

Comment: maybe you need `_user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE'`

Comment: @NoSssweat Adding `_user_is_logged_in: 'FALSE"` as a requirement in `mymodule.links.menu.yml` and clearing caches doesn't hide the link from my admin account when logged in.

Comment: Are you saying `route_name: user.register` instead of the `url: ...` didn't work?

Comment: @MPD That's what I thought, so I edited, but upon further testing, it looks like `route_name: user.register` is ok, but like `url` still shows for admins.

Comment: This is a really interesting question.  Since, you are using the 'internal:' scheme, there is no difference between using that and the route name (though, you should really use the route name.  Both will end going through the path validator, and authenticated users should get an access denied.  But, there is an `AccessDeniedSubscriber` to redirect authenticated users to their edit pages.  I think that is the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Structure of routes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643)

> **_role**: A specific Drupal role, eg. 'administrator'. You can specify multiple ones via "," for AND and "+" for OR logic. Note that, since
>   the roles available may differ between sites, it's recommended to use
>   permission based access restriction when possible.

so try

```
requirements:
  _role: anonymous
```

Comment: The link still shows up for users with the `admin` role, but it is hidden for `authenticated` users, which is good enough for me.

Comment: Perhaps it may only show for super admin (user #1) and not the other admins.

Comment: No, I was testing from an additional admin account.

Comment: @PatrickKenny okies